# Return value in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I need help with a query in Access. I need to return a customer name who has three or more orders within the past 14 days as of today's date that are still active. It also should display the orderdates in the results. This will populate on a report and grouped by the "cusname" and show each "orderdate". I tried using the query wizard and entering in  the below sql but it populates no results. Can someone please help?

```
Select customerid, count(*), cusname,orderdate,orderstatus
From tablename
Where orderstatus="active"
Group by customerid,cusname,orderdate,orderstatus
Having Count(*) >=3;
```

Table:

```
CusName:|orderdate:
Mary     4/4/2021
Mary     4/3/2021
Mary     4/8/2021
Mary     3/23/2021
Bob      4/9/2021
Bob      4/1/2021
```

What I expect the result to be :

Table:

```
Customerid:|CusName:|orderdate:
1 Mary     4/4/2021
1 Mary     4/3/2021
1 Mary     4/8/2021
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather tricky in MS Access, but you can use:

```
select t.*
from tablename as t
where t.orderstatus = "active" and
      t.orderdate in (select top 3 t2.orderdate
                      from tablename t2
                      where t2.customerid = t.customerid and
                            t2.orderstatus = "active" and
                            t2.orderdate > dateadd("day", -14, date())
                      order by t2.orderdate desc
                     ) and
      3 <= (select count(*)
            from tablename as t3
            where t3.customerid = t.customerid and
                  t3.orderstatus = "active" and
                  t3.orderdate > dateadd("day", -14, date())
           );
```

The first subquery gets the most recent three rows for each customer.  The second checks that there are at least three.

Comment: thank you. i just want to make sure because access is as you say tricky.. is using TOP the only way I would be able to display the dates associate with active status within the 14 day period?

Comment: @Neptune12 . . . I missed the 14 day condition so I added it to the query.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should put filter on date as well
2. you probably shouldn't group by order date, if you're trying to count the "unique orders per customer" but not "unique orders per customer per date"

```
SELECT customer_id, cusname, COUNT(*) 
  FROM <tablename> 
 WHERE ABS(DateDiff('d', order_date, NOW())) <= 14 -- check order date
   AND order_status = 'active'                     -- check order status
 GROUP BY customer_id, cusname                     -- group by customer, not by order
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3                               -- filter customers with 3+ orders
```

Comment: thank you but yours is similar to mine.  I tested yours and it didn't work in access either. Also, in group by I have to add in the orderdate,orderstatus because of the aggregate.

Comment: If you need such `GROUP BY`, then it's possible to use that query as a subquery in `WHERE` clause as source of `customer_id`s: `SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE customer_id IN (<query>) GROUP BY <anything>`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT t.customerid,
       t.cusname,
       t.orderdate,
       t.orderstatus
FROM   tablename AS t
WHERE  t.orderstatus = "active"
       AND t.orderdate > Dateadd("d", -14, DATE())
       AND (SELECT Count(t1.cusname)
            FROM   tablename AS t1
            WHERE  t.customerid = t1.customerid
                   AND t1.orderstatus = "active"
                   AND t1.orderdate > Dateadd("d", -14, DATE())) >= 3
```